# Trying to append dates in R but the time component is being dropped?

Tags: r, date

I have come across this problem. Consider an array of dates:

```
> y <- c("2012-01-02 10:00:00", "2012-01-03 09:00:00")
> as.POSIXct(y)
[1] "2012-01-02 10:00:00" "2012-01-03 09:00:00"
```

Now consider the same array with "2012-01-04 00:00:00". This vector has already undergone as.POSIXct, hence we get c("2012-01-02 10:00:00", "2012-01-03 09:00:00", "2012-01-04"). Then

```
> y <- c("2012-01-02 10:00:00", "2012-01-03 09:00:00", "2012-01-04")
> as.POSIXct(y)
[1] "2012-01-02 GMT" "2012-01-03 GMT" "2012-01-04 GMT"
```

Now the times have been dropped from all the dates rather than just adding back 00:00:00 to 2012-01-04. I've played around with formatting POSIXct and strptime, but am not getting anywhere. For example:

```
> as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
[1] "2011-03-27 GMT"
```

How can I retrieve the correct values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using `anytime`

```
anytime::anytime(y)
#[1] "2012-01-02 10:00:00 IST" "2012-01-03 09:00:00 IST" "2012-01-04 00:00:00 IST"
```

Note that `anytime` have a default set of `format`s.  We can find those with `getFormats()`.  If the format is not in the list, then use the `addFormats` to add a format

---

Or another way is by using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(y, guess_formats(y, c('ymd', 'ymd_HMS')))
#[1] "2012-01-02 10:00:00 UTC" "2012-01-03 09:00:00 UTC" "2012-01-04 00:00:00 UTC"
```

---

We guess the problem stems from the multiple `format` in the input `vector` and `as.POSIXct` takes only a single `format`, so probably it unifies the format to a single one by removing the time substring from the other elements.  This was tested on `R 3.4.0` and on `R 3.1.3` and both get the same output as in the OP's post